# Loading JS script after that Kendo grid be loaded

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, kendo-grid, nopcommerce

this is a part of my cshtml code in NopCommerce:

```
new ColumnProperty(nameof(BusinessUnitCustomerModel.Approved))
{
Title = T("Admin.BusinessUnit.Customers.Fields.Approved").Text,
ClassName =  NopColumnClassDefaults.CenterAll,
Render = new RenderSwitchButton("", T("Admin.BusinessUnit.Customers.Fields.ToggleApprove").Text)
{
OnClickFunctionName =  "toggleApprovedCustomer",
OnLoadFunction = "toggleApprovedCustomerLoad"
},Data=nameof(BusinessUnitCustomerModel.CustomerBusinessUnitId)
},
```

I write a JS script wanna be loaded after the page loading is finished.
This is my script code below:

```
<script asp-location="Footer">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.alert($('.switchbuttongrid').length())
    })
    function toggleApprovedCustomerLoad(elem, data) {
        var postData = {
            id: data
        };
        addAntiForgeryToken(postData);
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("ToggleApprove", "BusinessUnit"))",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                updateTable('#businessunitCustomers-grid');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?
(I need this script load after the page loading is done)